# voice acting of numbers in English in pyttsx3

Tags: python, audio, pyttsx3

I am writing a pastry shop with voice acting.
Voice - installed in windows.
Windows in Russian.
Library - pyttsx3

I have a dictionary:
{cake: description, cost, quantity}

```
pastry = {'napoleon': [['butter', 'flour', 'sugar'], 7, 1000],
          'honey cake': [['flour', 'butter', 'sugar'], 4, 1025],
          'kiev': [['sugar', 'flour', 'butter'], 5, 985]}
```

faced with the fact that everything is spoken in English, except for numbers
For example, this code sounds like this:

```
engine.say(f'The cake {cake} {v [2]} grams left')
```

The cake honey одна тысяча двадцать пять grams left'

Please tell me how to make the numbers sound in English too
Maybe you know another library that accurately sound the numbers or  can set this up in this